# Create a hyperlink that has the structure of a web page

Tags: html

I was listening to Security Now and I could swear that Steve Gibson mentioned that you could define the structure of a page within the hyperlink itself. Ill give you an example, obviously non functional:

```
<a href="<h1>THIS IS THE PAGE</h1>" target="_blank">This link makes a page</a>
```

If anyone has an exmple of doing this I would appreciate posting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by embedding the HTML source in a [`data:` URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

As an example, paste the following into your address bar.  (StackOverflow does no recognize data URIs)

```
data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%20lang%3D%22en%22%3E%3Chead%3E%3Ctitle%3EEmbedded%20Window%3C%2Ftitle%3E%3C%2Fhead%3E%3Cbody%3E%3Ch1%3EI'm%20a%20page!%3C%2Fh1%3E%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E
```

Comment: @How did you create it? :)

Comment: @YairNevet: `'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(...)`